# Python: adding an attribute to a variable of a class and have it survive assignment (descriptor class)

Tags: python

our project collects a bunch of information on an object from a bunch of different sources and for auditing and for resolving conflicts between our data sources we need to keep a bunch of meta data about each attribute

```
age = 21
age_metadata = {
     'source' : 'office gossip',
     'relability' : 0 
    {
```

the problem is the classes start to look like this.

```
class Person
    def __init__(self, id, ):
       self.id = id
       self.id_meta = None
       self.age = None
       self.age_meta = None
       self.name = None
```

which looks ugly and doubles the number of attributes everything has so what I want is to nest the metadata under each attribute. so if I need it I can call  `bob.age.meta` instead of `bob.age_meta` and I want to do this while leaving the attributes more or less unchanged. so I want something that always me to use it like:

```
def main():
    bob = Person(1)
    bob.age.meta = 'random metadata'
    bob.age = 30
    assert bob.age.meta == 'random metadata'
```

Now I think this should be possible using a combo of a descriptor class to intercept the assignment  + some monkey patching/ metaclassing magic to preserve the metadata.. but I'm new to all these features and am getting very lost. here is my current sketch.long way from working code:

```
class AttributeWithMeta(object):
    """interceot attribute fucntions"""

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self._value

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        """take  attribute and somehow replace it with monkey patched version"""
        self._value = magic(value,meta)

    @staticmethod
    def magic(value, meta):
        """adds meta attribute to objects regardless of type"""
        return  value_with_meta


class Person(object):
    age = AttributeWithMeta()

    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
```

Am I going in the right direction?  is there some other way to do this that I'm missing? Am I trying to do the impossible here?

P.S worst case  `age.get_meta()` would be acceptable if attributes are problematic.

Comment: Alternately, this looks like a good thing to model in a database. You could do sqlalchemy + sqlite for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bob.age.meta
   ^   ^
   |   |_______ This lookup can be managed by type(bob.age) class
   |
   |___________ This lookup can be managed by type(bob) class, i.e. Person
```

The attribute access of `.meta` is handled entirely by the `bob.age` object, so your `Person` class gets no say in the matter here.

By defining descriptors on `Person` class, you can control how setting/getting/deleting the `age` attribute behaves on a `Person` instance.  You [own the dot](https://twitter.com/raymondh) between a person instance and an attribute, and can do anything you want there. But that power does not reach as far as the 2nd dot - i.e. the `.` between `age` and `meta`.

If you want `bob.age` to return literally the integer 30, then you are going to have a hard time getting `bob.age.meta` to do anything but raise `AttributeError`.  That's because you would need a descriptor to be defined on the `int` class, now, and monkey-patching built-in types is not possible in python.  Not without [terrible and unreliable hacks](https://github.com/clarete/forbiddenfruit), anyway.

If you are happy for `bob.age` to return some kind of container of an object and the associated metadata, then what you want is possible with descriptors on the `Person` class.  But if you want `bob.age` to return only the object, and `bob.age.meta` to return only the metadata, then I think you're barking up the wrong tree.

A much less complicated design would be for each `Person` instance to have a `meta` dict directly, so that you could look up for example `bob.meta['age']` for the metadata related to bob's `age` attribute.

Comment: thanks  so I think I'm on the right track,  I'm ok if  `age` no longer  the built in type  but is instead a container that defers all of its methods except  `__set__` and __meta__  to its ._value  attribute which it defers it ._meta